# Getting "file not found: Main.java" when trying to work with command line in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command

So I wrote same question yesterday but it was closed due to the lack of specifics.
I'm simply trying to run my Main class by terminal. My code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Java");
   }
}
```

My classpath: C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand\src
In terminal :  Directory of C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand

I've tried : -cp C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand\src and

set CLASSPATH = C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand;C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand\src

Still: file not found: Main.java when typing : javac Main.java

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This isn't a classpath issue (yet). What directory is your console in, and what directory is the source file in? `javac Main.java` assumes that `Main.java` is in the current directory.

Comment: When I type "dir" it shows: Directory of C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand

Comment: And in my computer file is located in: C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand\src

Comment: Right. So do `cd src` first, so you're in the same directory as your source code.

Comment: So I runned it with coverage manually and I got that my classpath is: C:\Users\48790\IdeaProjects\workingWithCommand\out\production\workingWithCommand

Comment: Still has no idea why

Comment: "So I runned it with coverage manually" - um, that sounds like you're now looking at a *completely different problem*. If javac is now working and you've got a different problem, you should describe that (in *much* more detail than "I runned it with coverage manuall") in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler (`javac`) does not use the classpath for the files given as argument.

try `javac src\Main.java`

or

change to `src` (`cd src`) and then `javac Main.java`

The **file** given as argument to `javac` is a file as used for any other command of that operation system. The **classes** used by the program are searched using the classpath or `-cp`.

(to *execute* a class you use `java Main` (not `java Main.class`) because the argument is not a file<sup>**1**</sup>, but a class name - this is searched using the classpath or `-cp` option)

---

<sup>**1** - with newer Java versions, a single source file can be executed and compiled on the fly by : `java Main.java` (now it is a file, similar to a script)</sup>

Comment: Okay now I get the difference, thank you very much, it worked :)